# bootstrap label text stick to downline of input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a file upload styling with bootstrap. Following code works good but the problem is that the label `Choose file` stick with a downline of the input field. How can I make `Choose file` in the middle of an input field? To get a better idea check picture bellow-

[image: pic]

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to set the line height of the label to the height of your input box.

Comment: tried already not works. input height not gets increased at all

Comment: Does you input have padding set? top and bottom. Also can you provide the CSS used as well.

Comment: The code as is works for me, are you sure you don't have some CSS clashing somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 try Switching to Bootstrap 4 it works fine.

The CDN link you can include

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Or you might have used any CSS in the parent class of input field try checking that
[Same code you provided gives correct output (i have included above link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPLyh.png)